# Regex help for somebody that realy need help - Visual basic

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm actually starting creating a small language (in vb net, yes I know, maybe not a good idea).

I already started learning tutorials about regex, but apparently this function is saying me to get out).

I want to add some kind of commands, such as a command that allow you to arg. a `/print` command, something like:

```
/PRINT["Hello world";"blue";propety:{bold;italic}]
```

So, for me, the regex is :

```
"{{^\^{\|^@\^~\{}~\^]|\~^[}^\}^@~\[}~^\}^@#{\~{^}^#\@~#}\^#}^]|\|}]#\|{"
```

So you understand that's not something I like writing.

Would you show me how to construct regex code for the first command I let?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the regex is supposed to do?

Comment: And are you thinking that RegEx is a command?  Your first bullet you ask for commands.  RegEx (Regular Expressions) are not commands - - They are descriptions of patterns used to match against strings.

Comment: Questions that ask us to do an unrealistic amount of work are off-topic here.  What have you tried and *why didn't it work*?  You won't be able to complete your project if you can't do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, sure... I also type the code in visual basic, and, can you also just exmplain me how to get data (string) between 2 chars

Answer (score 1):

Regex alone isn't the best way to create a language that, well, actually works.
Read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50377/Create-Your-Own-Programming-Language) for more info. I'm sure you can find better way to write a language if you really need to write it. In vb.net...

Anyway, if you insist on writing it in vb, I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nux0ktE9t7Y) that will help you with it.